# `ModbusSerialClient` from `pymodbus.client.sync` vs. `pymodbus.client`

Tags: python, serial-port, pymodbus

I've been using pymodbus to comminicate with a temperature sensor. Previously, I used:

```py
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
```

and everything worked fine.

After a recent update, this was no longer possible (`pymodbus.client.sync` seems to have been removed, and I was getting an import error) and I had to switch to:

```py
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient
```

The import now works, but none of my previous commands do. I've just spent the last 3 hours scouring the documentation and can't work out *why* this no longer works. I can communicate with my device using `minimalmodbus`, so I am confident that the device is working fine.

What have I missed? Any ideas?!